# Running out of memory using keras ConvLSTM2D

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, lstm

I am trying to build a classifier (3 classes) for a time-varying signal that has 3 channels. I convert a few seconds of each channel to an amplitude-spectrum and use a window of 4 of these as an "image", so my features are N time-steps x 3 channels x 320 spectrum values x 4. N is typically thousands. I batch the time-steps into groups of 10. In the code below, nFilters=20, kernelSize=3, nTrFramesBatch=2684, nChannels=3, imageSize=4, nFreqVals=320

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(ConvLSTM2D(nFilters, kernel_size=(kernelSize, kernelSize)
                   , input_shape=(nTrFramesBatch, nChannels, imageSize, nFreqVals)
                   , padding='same'
                   , data_format='channels_first'
                   , return_sequences=True))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(AveragePooling3D((1, imageSize, nFreqVals), data_format='channels_first', padding='same'))
model.add(Reshape((-1, nFilters)))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='sigmoid'))
model.summary()
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])
```

This produces the following model:

```
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv_lst_m2d_1 (ConvLSTM2D)  (None, 2684, 20, 4, 320)  15920     
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (Batch (None, 2684, 20, 4, 320)  1280      
_________________________________________________________________
average_pooling3d_1 (Average (None, 2684, 20, 1, 1)    0         
_________________________________________________________________
reshape_1 (Reshape)          (None, 2684, 20)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 2684, 3)           63        
=================================================================
Total params: 17,263
Trainable params: 16,623
Non-trainable params: 640
```

However, running on a GPU, after a wait, I get the following error:

"Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[10,20,4,320] and type float on..."

I can't believe the machine can't allocate 10x20x4x320 = 256000 floats, and it does run much larger models than this one. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the question? The model is just too big for the platform you are running.

Comment: What kind of GPU does your machine have? Did you monitor current usage of this GPU? Are other processes using it as well? Also, please show the entire error message.

Comment: The question is: "Why am I running out of memory when the model is apparently very modest, with only 16k parameters to estimate?".

Comment: Not sure how to monitor GPU usage, but I have used this GPU successfully for models with over 1 000 000 parameters. As far as I know, GPU only allows a single process at any time. Complete error message is:

Comment: Epoch 1/8
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "U:\sleepwork\newdata-work\keras9.py", line 179, in <module>
    model.fit(trX, trY, epochs=nEpochs, verbose=1)

  File "C:\Apps\Anaconda3\envs\pythongpu\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1239, in fit
    validation_freq=validation_freq)

Comment: File "C:\Apps\Anaconda3\envs\pythongpu\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_arrays.py", line 196, in fit_loop
    outs = fit_function(ins_batch)

  File "C:\Apps\Anaconda3\envs\pythongpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py", line 3292, in __call__
    run_metadata=self.run_metadata)

  File "C:\Apps\Anaconda3\envs\pythongpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1458, in __call__
    run_metadata_ptr)

ResourceExhaustedError: 2 root error(s) found.

Comment: (0) Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[10,20,4,320] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
  [[{{node conv_lst_m2d_1/while/convolution_2}}]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.

  [[Mean/_153]]

Comment: Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.

  (1) Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[10,20,4,320] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
  [[{{node conv_lst_m2d_1/while/convolution_2}}]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.

0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.

Comment: The traceback is much more readable if you put it in your question. Memory usage is not only determined by parameters, but also by the size of the outputs of each layer, so having a model with 16K parameter means nothing regarding memory use.